# Remote desktop connection over Internet through VPN

Tags: 16.04, gnome, vpn, remote-desktop, vnc

I have a desktop computer in my lab at my university, and I have a laptop that I take with myself. Both systems run [Ubuntu GNOME 16.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME). The lab desktop has an **internal static** IP address provided by my university, while the laptop connects over WiFi and has a dynamic IP address. My main use case would be to **connect to my desktop PC from my laptop**, from anywhere.

My university provides VPN to access the university network from anywhere. Previously, when I was a Windows user (dark ages, that was) I could connect to the VPN, and then using the Windows remote desktop, enter the internal IP of my desktop, and get connected. Now, I am looking for a similar solution for [Ubuntu GNOME 16.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME).

I had been using Teamviewer for remote access, but, it often got stuck, and had many other issues (like color rendering, screen resolution, lag, etc.). I am looking for an opensource software built to handle my use case. Having built in VPN support would be perfect.

From reading countless forum posts, it appears that [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/) is the best VNC program. However, all user guides for [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/), [Remmina](https://www.remmina.org/wp/), [Vinagre](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Vinagre), and other VNC programs seem to require a server configuration, with a static public IP address. It is not possible to get a static public IP for my desktop. Neither can I configure custom port forwarding.

Comment: I understand that you can't configure port forwarding (you may, at most, request it at your IT department) but what I don't understand is your starting with *The lab desktop has an internal static IP address* and later *It is not possible to get a static public IP for my desktop*... What gives?

Comment: In my head, public ip is something that is visible to the world, and can directly be used to connect to some place. Like Google.com has many a public ip. Conversely, internal ip is something assigned by a router to the machine, and is unaccessible from the world outside unless the router forwards the port.

Comment: Why does it matter if you're using a VPN? Once in the network the internal IPs is what matter.

Comment: Hey! Actually, now that I think about it, after connecting to the VPN, it is as good as I am on the network of my uni. So, it should not need ports forwarded... Thanks @MichaelBay

Comment: Indeed, it shouldn't need forwarding ;) And if you used rtemote desktop from Windows before it means the machine is set to allow such connection. If so, using Remmina should be the same. Why haven't you tried it? Just setup a new connection, same IP, same protocol as before...

Comment: That was funny, the way your first comment jogged my thoughts about VPN. Anyway, what would you recommend I use for remote desktop, Tiger, Remmina, Real, Vinagre, something else?

Comment: Remmina should be familiar to you if you used the Windows app before ;)

Comment: Thanks! The reason I asked the question is all the online guides confused me into a twist. I was so occupied with port forwarding, public and private addresses, that I did not think... Thank you a bunch! Please post your comments as answer and I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in a VPN you don't have to worry about other than the internal IPs or worry about port forwarding. Those concepts are fundamental for connecting from the outside of said network without a VPN.

> Previously (...) I could connect to the VPN (...) using the Windows Remote Desktop, enter the internal IP of my desktop, and get connected.

This means the desktop you want to remotely access is already set up for allowing such remote connections.

You can do the same with [Remmina](https://www.remmina.org/wp/) in Ubuntu. It is usually installed by default but if not it can be installed from the Ubuntu Software or using `sudo apt install remmina`. Just configure a new connection for the same IP and using the same protocol and settings as before. Having used the Windows app before you'll find Remmina quite familiar.

Comment: One minor correction, both systems run Ubuntu now, the Windows bit is from the long-lost time when both ran Windows, some 3 years ago. So I have to set up Remmina on both systems.

Comment: It doesn't matter from which OS you're accessing from. If the target machine wasn't changed since, it is already set up for those connections. If not yet then sure, you need to enable remote access as before. In Ubuntu it's done at Remote Desktop Preferences (or remote sharing or something... My current Ubuntu is not English).